# Is there any way to force Chrome to render fractional pixel font sizes accurately?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, layout

I am having issues with accurate font rendering in Chrome and wondering if anyone here can provide some advice. I need to precisely fill an allotted width with text, which I'm accomplishing via some simple JavaScript.

The JS works well, and correctly applies a fractional font-size value to each of my width-filling spans, and it looks great in Firefox/IE. But, the appearance is very spotty in Chrome because it rounds font sizes to the nearest integer pixel value.

An excellent illustration of the problem can be found [in this recently filed Chromium issue.](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=254056)  Looking at this simple markup sample, you can clearly see Chrome's font-size rounding:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div style='font-size: 10px'>Text Text Text Text</div>
        <div style='font-size: 10.4px'>Text Text Text Text</div>
        <div style='font-size: 10.5px'>Text Text Text Text</div>
        <div style='font-size: 11px'>Text Text Text Text</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Chrome rendering:

[image: Chrome font size]

Firefox rendering:

[image: Firefox font size]

IE9 rendering:

[image: IE9 font size]

Obviously it's a bad sign that the best reference I could find for what I need to do is in the Chromium issue tracker...but I thought it couldn't hurt to ask.  Can anyone suggest a workaround?  CSS or JS solutions are both fine - anything to get those fonts more accurate!

Comment: Chrome (on Windows) really *really* sucks at rendering text. All I know is that they are working on it... :( Would be great if somebody could tell me otherwise though.

Comment: I suppose it's worth mentioning that I see this behavior in Chrome on both Windows and Mac.

Comment: As of `Chrome 37.0.2062.102 m`, the problem appears to be resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only workaround that occurs to me would involve applying `-webkit-transform: scale(x)`, example:

```
div[style*="10."]  {-webkit-transform-origin: 0 50%;}
div[style*="10.1"] { -webkit-transform: scale(1.01);}
div[style*="10.2"] { -webkit-transform: scale(1.02);}
div[style*="10.3"] { -webkit-transform: scale(1.03);}
div[style*="10.4"] { -webkit-transform: scale(1.04);}
div[style*="10.5"] { -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);}
div[style*="10.6"] { -webkit-transform: scale(0.96);}
div[style*="10.7"] { -webkit-transform: scale(0.97);}
div[style*="10.8"] { -webkit-transform: scale(0.98);}
div[style*="10.9"] { -webkit-transform: scale(0.99);}
```

The problem, I guess, is that since you are auto-fitting text you are probably getting `element.offsetWidth` which will give you the width before the scaling. To get it after being scaled use `element.getBoundingClientRect().width` (your library might already take care of this). You can see this in action here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Cfd5a/

Comment: Looks promising, I'll check this option out.

Comment: I actually wasn't getting the offsetWidth--I was deriving the amount to scale my text by with a hackier solution. Between that property and -webkit-transform/-transform, I was able to solve my problem. Thanks!